# Why use a tree structure to support searching?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree

For example, the `BST` class uses a tree structure:

```
   public class BST<Key extends Comparable<Key>,Value> {
      private Node root;
      public class Node {
         private int n;
         private Node left;
         private Node right;
         private Key key;
         private Value val;
      }
      public void put();
      public Value get(Key key)
   }
```

In this structure, nodes are connected with `left` and `right` fields and inserts and search is supported with `put` and `get` methods.

I'm interested in knowing

- how are the nodes created?
- why use a tree structure rather than array or some other simple structure?

Comment: You could implement this using an array, but that would be more along the lines of a heap. With creating nodes, it is basically one piece in memory that is pointing to other parts of memory. Its very similar to a linked list, except you give it additional properties. Keep in mind that all of these are "absract data types", meaning that they are mainly an idea to help us understand how to manipulate data.

Comment: Are you wanting to know why the left, right pointers create a BST structure? or are you wanting to know how the put/get methods work with the BST?

Comment: A very good reference is http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/32bst/ and the associated code at http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/32bst/BST.java.html explaining all you need to know !!

Answer (score 0):

The key advantage of a tree structure for searching is efficiency. It is possible to reach the node matching the key you are searching for much more quickly than iterating through an array (for example). If you have a balanced binary tree (i.e. the depth of the tree to the left and right of any node differs by no more than 1) of 1024 items then you will need step through a maximum of 10 nodes to find the key. There are special cases for arrays (such as evenly distributed values) that can be searched just as efficiently but trees are very good for a wide variety of situations which involve lots more searches than inserts.

On the other hand, inserting values into trees can be inefficient, particularly due to the need to rebalance the tree to allow efficient searching (which is their main purpose). This makes the `put` method relatively complicated (depending on which balancing algorithm you use).

The `get` method is pretty trivial:

```
public Value get(Key key) {
    Node node = root;
    while (node != null) {
        int compare = key.compareTo(node.key);
        if (compare > 0)
            node = node.right;
        else if (compare < 0)
            node = node.left;
        else
            return node.val;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very well explained [here](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/32bst/) and [here](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/32bst/BST.java.html). To summarize - this is how the nodes are created.

```
/**
 * Inserts the key-value pair into the symbol table, overwriting the old value
 * with the new value if the key is already in the symbol table.
 * If the value is <tt>null</tt>, this effectively deletes the key from the symbol table.
 *
 * @param  key the key
 * @param  val the value
 * @throws NullPointerException if <tt>key</tt> is <tt>null</tt>
 */
public void put(Key key, Value val) {
    if (val == null) {
        delete(key);
        return;
    }
    root = put(root, key, val);
    assert check();
}

private Node put(Node x, Key key, Value val) {
    if (x == null) return new Node(key, val, 1);
    int cmp = key.compareTo(x.key);
    if      (cmp < 0) x.left  = put(x.left,  key, val);
    else if (cmp > 0) x.right = put(x.right, key, val);
    else              x.val   = val;
    x.N = 1 + size(x.left) + size(x.right);
    return x;
}
```

If the key already exists - it's replaced and if the key is new it is recursively searched till the search ends at a leaf - the leaf is then expanded with the new node. It's important to note that the final position of the node is the place where search would have ultimately found it if it were already in the tree so as to satisfy the BST properties.

Also due to properties of Binary search tree - the search operation is O(log n) or O(h) where n is number of nodes and h is height of tree.